# Change datacapture encoding data to csv

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm using sagemaker model monitor.

When capturing data, it outputs the following json file.

```
{"captureData":{"endpointInput":{"observedContentType":"text/csv","mode":"INPUT","data":"MSwwLjUzLDAuNDIsMC4xMzUsMC42NzcsMC4yNTY1LDAuMTQxNSwwLjIx","encoding":"BASE64"},"endpointOutput":{"observedContentType":"text/csv; charset=utf-8","mode":"OUTPUT","data":"MTEuNjQzNDU1NTA1MzcxMDk0","encoding":"BASE64"}},"eventMetadata":{"eventId":"33404924-c0d4-4044-9dc2-1e1f5575cb0a","inferenceTime":"2020-06-04T05:45:45Z"},"eventVersion":"0"}
```

I want the encoding to be csv but somehow it outputs base64.
When or where do we change the setting of the encoding?
Is it during the invoking the endpoint? or set when making endpoint config.
I looked for some documents but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just came across this same problem! Seems like you need to specify `CaptureContentTypeHeader` params to tell SageMaker which content type headers to treat as CSV (or JSON), versus the default which is to base64 encode the payload!

So e.g. adding the following to your [CreateEndpointConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateEndpointConfig.html) call or boto3/sagemaker SDK equivalent should fix it:

```
{
   "DataCaptureConfig": { 
      "CaptureContentTypeHeader": { 
         "CsvContentTypes": [ "text/csv" ]
      },
   }
}
```

I guess this is to allow for non-standard Content-Type headers? Providing a layer of config to resolve e.g:

- `application/x-mycoolmodel` -> `JSON`, versus
- `application/x-secretsauce` -> `BASE64`